# Company Community: What is 'Read Only' workflow approvals?

Tags: community, workflow

Comparison of different Communities User Licenses is here -> https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US

'Workflow Approvals' are available 'Read only' in Company Community, no such restriction in Customer Community Plus or Partner Community.

What exactly is 'Read Only'? What capability which is available to non 'Read-Only' restriction user is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a Workflow Approval is read-only, it means it can be viewed, but can't be modified. In essence, a Customer Community user wouldn't be able to do the approval from the Customer Community side of things. All they could do is view the workflow approval record.

A Customer Community Plus license and a Partner Community license both have totally different sharing models than a regular Customer Community. When a record can be shared as other than read-only, it can be edited or modified (and in some rare cases deleted), meaning a user in one of those communities could potentially be one of the approvers used in a Workflow Approval process. In a regular Customer Community, a user cannot possibly be an approver.